# what is the equivalent of delphi's TClientDataSet.PacketRecords in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, datatable

If I read data into a datatable using the Adapter.Fill() method the entire resultset is loaded into the datatable.
When there are many records this can take a second or 2 and since it is in the loading of the form the form takes a few seconds to show itself.

In delphi I could use a TClientDataSet with packetrecords set to 50 for example to make it not load the entire table when opening and only fetch more records when needed.

Is there a way to do the same in C# using simple datatable components ?
The  application is binding all data-aware controls to a bindingsource, that is bound to a datatable that is filled by the Adapter.Fill() method.

Comment: i used to use Adapter for my application, but this days i use Linq and EF and i suggested you to try it.
but in your case you have to make a pagination.for doing pagination you have some chooses, Like DataView ,Collection , etc

Comment: You would have use a DataReader and fill the DataTable once record at a time.  You would still have a delay waiting for 1st record to be retrieved from the database.  You may also have a delay between each record waiting for the database to get next value.  The DataReader is using IEnumerator method.

Comment: I am not a fan of EF, but I will have a look at Linq. Is there any usefull documentation I can read that also explains how to do pagination ?

Comment: I have added the winforms tag to my question to make clear I need this for a winforms project

Answer (score 0):

Method Fill have overload :

```
public int Fill(int startRecord, int maxRecords, params DataTable[] dataTables);
```

Comment: and does it just like the delphi TClientDataSet fetches more records when needed ? Like for example when the user scrolls down in datagrid ?